# Calculus by Apostol Exercise 2.8 number 1

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

[image: Problem]

It is unclear to me on how to prove part (a), but what I did is, given $\sin(nπ)=0$, I proved by induction, so if $k=1$ then $\sin(π)=0$ which is trivial, then assume $\sin(kπ)=0$, I have to prove that $\sin((k+1)π)=0$. So given $\sin(kπ)=0$, I multiplied $\cos(π)$ both sides to get $$\sin(kπ)\cos(π)=0,$$ then added $\cos(kπ)\sin(π)$ both sides to get $$\sin(kπ)\cos(π)+\cos(kπ)\sin(π)=\cos(kπ)\sin(π),$$ but the right hand side is $0$ because $\sin(π)=0$, then $$\sin(kπ)\cos(π)+\cos(kπ)\sin(π)=0,$$ $\sin(kπ+π)=0$, $\sin((k+1)π)=0$. Hence $\sin(nπ)=0$. QED

Seems ok with me but still unsure, but given it is correct, I don't know how to start with what he is asking in part (a), prove that it is the only solution such that $\sin(x)=0$ with $x=nπ$. Also part (b) is confusing me on how to start. Any help?

Comment: What's your definition of $\sin(x)$?

Comment: Apostol didn't define sine explicitly, he just stated that sin is a periodic function that satisfies some fundamental properties. He assumed I am familiar with the sine function. So as I know sin is a function that is periodic and bounded by [-1,1] in the y-axis.

Comment: It is on a separate chapter,trigonometric functions has its own chapter. That is my confusion here, there is no explicit definition for sin and cos stated, so I just guessed by using induction, that is why I need suggestions if my proof is enough given that he didn't give any definition? Apostol even stated he is not so much concerned about the definitions of sin and cos, but rather focuses on the properties which are important to calculus.

Comment: Yes, apostol stated that he would give an analytic definition of sine and cosine until the chapter on series and sequences of functions, which is on chap 11, I'm still on chap 2... Given that circumstance, is my proof using induction enough?

Comment: Yes.  And really the only thing you're missing for the proof of uniqueness is knowing that $\theta=0$ and $\theta = \pi$ are the sole zeroes of $\theta \mapsto \sin(\theta)$ on $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and that $\sin(\theta +2\pi) = \sin(\theta)$ for all $\theta$ -- which can be inferred from the unit circle definition of $\sin$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the unit circle definition of $\sin$ (not the best definition, but without a better one, it'll have to do), we know that $\sin(0)=\sin(\pi)=0$.  Furthermore, we know that those are the only zeros on $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.  We also know that $\sin(\theta + 2\pi) = \sin(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in \Bbb R$.  Thus it can easily be proved by induction that $\sin(0 + 2\pi n) =0=\sin(\pi+2\pi n)$.

This implies that $\theta \in \{z \mid z=0 + 2\pi n \vee z=\pi + 2\pi n,\ n \in \Bbb Z\} = \{n\pi \mid n\in \Bbb Z\}$ are the only zeroes of $\theta \mapsto \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: I think your expression on the right is confusing, if you stated sin((((0+2π)+2π)+...+2π), it means you are adding 2π infinitely right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No.  Sorry.  I meant to add it $n$ times.  I edited the answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: Oh, so how would I state it? Using summation notation?

Comment: You don't even need to.  Just prove that $\sin(0+2\pi n)=\sin(0)=0$ by induction (knowing that by definition it works for $n=1$).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for these information! Very helpful!